# video.js loadedalldata firing only once?

Tags: video.js

The following code sets up video.js and listens on loadedalldata event to start playing and listens on ended event to load another file.  If an flv plays first, I get loadedalldata event for loading the flv, then it plays, I get the ended event, the mp4 loads, but I never get the loadedalldata event.

If the mp4 plays first, I get two loadedalldata events, the mp4 plays, I get the ended event, the flv loads, I get the loadedalldata event, the flv plays, I get the ended event, the flv loads again - but I never get the loadedalldata event.

If both vids are mp4, it plays in a loop (with two loadedalldata events each time).

So it seems, something about the flv playing disrupts the next loadedalldata event.
i event tried adding a .on('loadedalldata') event in the ended handler.  No change.

Any suggestions??

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="/js/video.js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/video.js/video.js"></script>

    <script>
        videojs.options.flash.swf = "/js/video.js/video-js.swf"
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var playIt = function playVid() {
                alert("Event");
                this.play();
            }

            videojs("video1", {}, function(){
                this.on('loadedalldata', playIt);
                this.on('ended', function() {
                    this.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: "/files/test.mp4" });
                    this.load();
                });
                this.src({ type: "video/flv", src: "/files/barsandtone.flv" });
                this.load();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"></video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that's a bug in Video.js when playing additional sources through Flash. With Flash, progress events are created manually in javascript as opposed to being able to use the native events like with html5. This line of code turns the events off as soon as the buffer reaches 100%, but then never resets itself on a later source load.

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/ce18a9af740eb2a01f2b0efe2d10299de32818ce/src/js/media/media.js#L192

It should restart these events when the `loadstart` event is fired again by the flash player, signaling a new source has been loaded. You should submit an issue on the video.js repo for this. https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/new

Comment: AOK.  Thanks for the answer.  Was hoping it was me, but seemed like it was probably a bug.  Will file bug report.